# Which is my wwan device?

Tags: networking, ip

I have a ThinkPad with [ThinkPad_mobile_Internet](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ThinkPad_mobile_Internet)

To enable it, I want to know my wwan device (like [this](https://github.com/penguin2716/qmi_setup/blob/master/qmi_setup.sh)):

```
# your wwan device name created by qmi_wwan kernel module
# check it with "ip a" or "ifconfig -a". it may be wwan0?
```

but my `ip a` return this:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wwp0s20f0u2i1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:29:c8:62:f2:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:99:57:c6:bc:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.22.142/20 brd 10.2.31.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp9s0
       valid_lft 3351sec preferred_lft 3351sec
    inet6 2001:da8:201:3041:7c3d:aaa0:95f7:5501/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591998sec preferred_lft 604798sec
    inet6 fe80::e328:2a26:59d9:3e37/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:f3:ab:4c:6e:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Which is my wwan device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two letters tell you the type of interface:

`lo` for loopback
`en` for Ethernet
`wl` for wireless LAN (WLAN)
`ww` for wireless wide area network (WWAN)

So in your case, you want `wwp0s20f0u2i1` and

`lo` is your loopback
`wlp9s0` is your wlan
`enp0s31f6` is your ethernet